# Can't change memory_limit on PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx, php, configuration, memory, php-fpm

I'm running PHP on Nginx using fpm. The reported memory_limit is 128M and i cannot change it for the life of me.

PHPInfo:

- Server API:    FPM/FastCGI
- Config file:   /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
- Memory limit:  128M

The memory_limit in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini is 256M

If i run `grep -Ri "memory_limit" /etc` it returns:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.dpkg-dist:;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M                    │Max: 921.53 kBit/s                              Max: 11.70 MBit/s
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M                              │Ttl: 233.43 kByte                               Ttl: 2.14 MByte
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:memory_limit = 256M                                                       │
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:memory_limit = -1
```

I have stopped nginx and php-fpm, done `sudo killall php-fpm` and restarted nginx and php-fpm. Memory_limit is still 128M.

[image: Phpinfo]

Please send help.

Comment: Reboot fixed it. Shouldn't be necessary though?

Comment: Wow ... I tried EVERYTHING and rebooting finally worked for me too.

Comment: I had the same issue. A reboot wasn't necessary; simple `apachectl graceful` was enough. Thanks for posting this question, though; it helped me realise what to try.